# Removing buttons from a view

Tags: cocoa, button, view, superview

Is there a way to clear the view of all buttons? My code generates buttons every second, and I made a button that I want to clear them all off the screen. When I tried `[brick.removeFromSuperview]` (brick being the name of the button), it only deleted the last button that was produced.

Comment: I'm curious... why is your app creating buttons every second? Is this some kind of game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep track of the references to all your buttons in an `NSMutableArray`.

e.x.

```
NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Button creation
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init...];
[yourView addSubview:button];
[buttons addObject:button];
[button release];

// Button removal
[buttons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
[buttons removeAllObjects];  // Alternatively, you could omit this line
                             // and recycle the buttons at a later time
```

An advantage of this method (as opposed to just enumerating the view's subviews and looking for buttons) is that you don't have to worry about removing UIButtons from your view that shouldn't be.  For example, if you don't want your "delete all buttons" button removed, just don't add it to the array.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (UIView *view in [self subviews]) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Careful though, this will literally delete all buttons from the specified view. So you probably want some kind of conditional to only delete the generated buttons. You could distinguish from generated buttons by setting a `tag` on your other buttons, if the button has no tag then remove it.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray * buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for( NSObject * btn in btn.superview.subviews )
{
  if( [btn isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]] )
    [buttons addObject: btn]; 
}

for( UIView * btn in buttons )
  [btn removeFromSuperview];

[buttons release];
```

The temporary array is required because removing the button invalidates the enumerator producing unpredictable results.